# Virtual attributes in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, attr-accessor, virtual-attribute

How can I use virtual attributes(getter, setter) in rails 4, as 'attr_accessible' removed.

I am getting issue, here

```
  def tags_list
    @tags = self.tags.collect(&:name).join(', ')
  end
```

I can reach above method, but not able to reach setter below, when trying to update/create.

```
  def tags_list=(tags)
    @tags = tags
  end
```

Comment: Are you getting attr_accessible and attr_accessor mixed up? attr_accessible has gone - to be replaced by strong parameters. But as far as I know, attr_accessor remains.

Comment: sorry, Its attr_accessor :tags_list

Comment: if you use attr_accessor you shouldn't need to define a getter or setter at all. attr_accessor is a macro that creates both of them for you.

Comment: I am new in ruby on rails.
My question is how to use virtual attributes in rails 4.

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135974/mongoid-w-rails-attr-accessible-no-method-found. I think you should not name your instance variable `@tags`, generally instance attributes with same name as getter are used by active record, `@tags_list` might be a better choice.

Comment: This should work in Rails 4 provided these aren't `protected` methods. The `attr_accessible` method has been deprecated because parameter validation is now done in the controller.

Answer (score 13):

Using virtual attributes in Rails 4 pretty much the same as with attr_accessible.  You just have to add your virtual attribute to the permitted params in your controller (instead of attr_accessible), then add the getter and setter methods as usual in your model.

```
# your_controller.rb
private

def your_model_params
  params.require(:your_model_name).permit(:tags_list)
end
```

Comment: But it does not work with #new and #create at the moment, which makes it pretty much useless, because you would have to write `your_virtual_attr=:something` separately all the time. Anyone else noticed this and has a clue on how to handle it?

Comment: I also noticed that calling `Tag.new(tags_list: [1, 2])` doesn't fire the `tags_list=()` virtual attribute.. is this a bug?

Comment: @phikes, is it just `before_action :your_model_params` ? You can optionally specfiy: , only: [:new, :create] or `exlcude: , except: [:action1, :action2, etc.]` .