# Mongoid w/ Rails, attr_accessible --> "No method found"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

- Generated Rails App w/out Active Record
- Added appropriate gems for Mongoid (Mongodb & Mongoid)
- Generated the mongoid.yml file in config/ with rails support
- Created a friend model and user controller with typical CRUD routes

Everything works except when I try to do a mass assignment I get:
`` "undefined method `attr_accesible' for Friend:Class" ``

Model, friend.rb:

```
    class Friend
      include Mongoid::Document
      field :first_name, :type => String
      field :last_name, :type => String
      field :adjective, :type => String
      attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :adjective
    end
```

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: first_development
        hosts:
          - localhost:27017
        options:
        options:
test:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: first_test
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        consistency: :strong
        max_retries: 1
        retry_interval: 0
```

Thoughts?

Comment: The link "http://paul-wong-jr.blogspot.com/2012/03/dynamic-attributes-and-mongodbmongoid.html" says to add attr_accessor :accessible below the attr_accessible line. The reason is "# :accessible is a variable used to store the game specific dynamic fields so that they can be set through mass assignment via attr_accessible. this allows the attr_accessible to be set dynamically."

Comment: I'm also encountering the same problem. @user1455116's suggestion did not work. Which version of rails and mongoid are you using?

Answer (score 26):

Ok, I have found the problem.

First of all, I assume you are using Rails 4. The reason you are getting this error is that `attr_protected` and `attr_accessible` have been removed from Rails 4 and placed in their own gem. Rails is now encouraging a new protection model. You can read about this in the [README](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters). If you would like to continue using the old behavior, you must include the [protected_attributes gem](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes). Hope that helps.

EDIT: I've added clarification below since this is likely to be a common problem with users to upgrading to rails 4.

If you would like to continue using `attr_accessible`, i.e. the Rails 3 way, simply add `gem protected_attributes` to your Gemfile.

If you would like to start doing things the Rails 4 way, you must no longer use `attr_accessible`. Instead, you must move the attribute permission logic into the controller. Here is an example:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # Using params[:user] without calling user_params will throw an error because 
    # the parameters were not filtered. This is just some Rails magic.
    @user = User.new user_params
    if @user.save
      # Do whatever
    else
      render action: :new
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    # params.require(:user) throws an error if params[:user] is nil

    if current_user.nil? # Guest
      # Remove all keys from params[:user] except :name, :email, :password, and :password_confirmation
      params.require(:user).permit :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
    elsif current_user.has_role :admin
      params.require(:user).permit! # Allow all user parameters
    elsif current_user.has_role :user
      params.require(:user).permit :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
    end
  end
```

Comment: your assumption is correct - i am using rails 4.  I'll check into this when i get on my development machine

Comment: Hey, so according to the readme you linked, it appears that the protection model is inside of rails. https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#compatibility  It says that it is bundled in with rails now, so i shouldn't have to use any gem to make this work.

Comment: The README file was for the `strong_parameters` gem, which is the current Rails 4 standard. The second link is to the `protected_attributes` gem. The `protected_attributes`gem contains the `attr_accessible` method, but `protected_attributes` was removed from Rails 4. If you would like to continue using the `attr_accessible` method in rails 4, you must add the following to your Gemfile: `gem 'protected_attributes'`

Comment: I did - but your answer was not the solution for my issue, hence only half the bounty - and I do appreciate your answer :)   The solution was - NOT TO USE IT!  `attr_accessible` seems to be just an optional thing when using devise / mongoid, so i just left it out, and things are working fine. the issue i was having was stemming from something else

Answer (score 0):

For any readers who are using Rails 5 and find out that the `protected_attributes gem` is not compatible:

You don't need `attr_accessible` since mass assignment is not possible anymore
https://www.rubyplus.com/articles/3281-Mass-Assignment-in-Rails-5